# Sum of infinite series inconsistent with Math.exp result

Tags: java, math

Background: I have the following code which calculates the Gaussian Function as a sum of an infinite series.
The [Gaussian Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), at it's simplest form is e^-(x^2).
This can be calculated as the sum of an infinite series, using the Taylor Series expansion.

Therefore, e^-(x^2) = 1 - (x^2) + (x^4)/2! - (x^6)/3! ....

```
public static double expSeries (double x, int n){
    double result = 0.0, x0 = 1.0, x1;
    result+= x0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        x1 = x0 * ((x*x)/i);
        if (i%2 == 0){
            result += x1;
        } else {
            result -= x1;
        }           
        x0 = x1;
    }
    return result;
    }
```

As a comparison, I use `Math.exp(-(x*x))` to see if my function works correctly.

The function seems to work for low values of `x`, but behaves inconsistently after that. Here are the output of a few test cases:

```
x=1; n=10
Result  : 0.3678794642857144
Math.exp: 0.36787944117144233

x=1; n=100
Result  : 0.36787944117144245
Math.exp: 0.36787944117144233

x=2; n=100
Result  : 0.018315638888733953
Math.exp: 0.01831563888873418

x=3; n=100
Result  : 1.234098038990534E-4
Math.exp: 1.2340980408667956E-4

x=4; n=100
Result  : 1.1247503313371918E-7
Math.exp: 1.1253517471925912E-7

x=5; n=100
Result  : 8.181278981021932E-7
Math.exp: 1.3887943864964021E-11

x=6; n=100
Result  : -0.03197975209642004
Math.exp: 2.319522830243569E-16

x=7; n=100
Result  : 3.6698962220692825E10
Math.exp: 5.242885663363464E-22
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I would guess Floating number precision ? You could try with BigDecimal to prevent this (if this is the reason)

Comment: Why are you dividing by `i` instead of `i factorial` ?

Comment: @AxelH: I did a few calculations on the largest values. When x=1 & n=100, 100! is calculated, which turns out to be 9.332622e+157. When x=5 & n=100, 5^200 is calculated, which is 6.223015e+139. If it was a range problem, I think it should have crashed with x=1 & n=100.

Comment: And where are you computing x^4, x^6, etc?

Comment: @jr593 : `(n+1)! = (n+1)n! `. I'm multiplying the current number to the denominator of the previous term, which effectively turns it into a factorial of the current number.

Comment: @EJP: The nth term is `x^2n / n!`. Therefore, the (n+1)th term is effectively the nth term multiplied by `(x^2) / (n+1)`. There is a minus sign involved, which I've delegated to the `if` branch.

Comment: @XSurgent, indeed!

Comment: I think you are correct actually. I rewrite with BigDecimal the math (with factorial) and for x=7,I have the same result, the diff with Math.exp is -3.6698962251221756E10. it is possible that Math.exp is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm looks fine and you are probably hitting the limits of double precision.

I would suggest to rewrite the algo for the Taylor series of exp(x) instead of exp(-x2), which is a little more straightforward to code:

```
public static double expSeries(double x, int n) {
  double term = 1;
  double result = term;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    term *= x / i;
    result += term;
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can then add an `expSeries_X2(x, i) { return expSeries(-x*x, i); }` if you want.

We can then rewrite that method using `BigDecimal`s:

```
public static double expSeries(double x, int n) {
  BigDecimal result = ONE;
  BigDecimal term = ONE;
  BigDecimal x_ = new BigDecimal(x);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    term = term.multiply(x_.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(i), MathContext.DECIMAL128));
    result = result.add(term);
  }
  return result.doubleValue();
}
```

And it should return a result that is closer to what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to use the more straightforward algorithm of exp(x). However, rewriting the method using `BigDecimal` gets me up to x=5, n=100 (For exp(-x^2)). After that, it becomes inconsistent as before. Am I now hitting the precision limits for `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @XSurgent try to increase the number of iterations - the convergence of the series takes longer for smaller values of x. With n = 200 I get something very close to `Math.exp` for x = 6. For x = 7, you will also need to increase the precision, for example with `new MathContext(50, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN))`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great lesson in problems with floating point numbers.

Taylor series is *not* always a good way to calculate a function value.

Look at the general definition [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html).  You're calculating the value of the function by *extrapolating* out from a certain point `a`.  In your case, that value is zero, so `exp(0) = 1`.  The further you go from zero, the worse the extrapolation.  So it is with all extrapolations, regardless of how you do it.

Even worse, you're depending on alternating signs of *very* large numbers to cancel each other out and give you something sensible.  If `x = 7` and `e = 2.71....`, how large a number is 2^49 or 3^49?  Very large, indeed.

I don't think the answer should be `BigDecimal`.  A better idea would be to understand exactly what you're doing and find out if there are better ways to approximate the function for large exponents.

Gaussian is used in statistics to model the normal distribution.  If you normalize the function parameter to the [Z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) (`Z = (x-xmean)/stddev`) you'll see that 99.9% of the area under the function falls in the range `-3 <= Z <= +3` (plus or minus three standard deviations).  You aren't likely to need parameter that falls outside that range.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewriten the formula with `BigDecimal`:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    for(int i=1;i < 8; ++i){
        double l = Math.exp(-(Math.pow(i, 2)));
        double r = expSeries(BigDecimal.valueOf(i), 100);
        System.out.println( l + " - " + r + " = " + (l - r) );
    }     
}

public static double expSeries (BigDecimal x, int n){
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE, x1;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        x1 = x.pow(i*2).divide(new BigDecimal(factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(i))), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            result = result.add(x1);
        }
        else{
            result = result.subtract(x1);
        }
    }
    return result.doubleValue();
}

public static BigInteger factorial (BigInteger num){
    if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0) return num;
    return num.multiply(
            factorial(num.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

And the result :

```
0.36787944117144233 - 0.36787944117144233 = 0.0
0.01831563888873418 - 0.01831563888873418 = 0.0
1.2340980408667956E-4 - 1.2340980408667956E-4 = 0.0
1.1253517471925912E-7 - 1.1253517471925912E-7 = 0.0
1.3887943864964021E-11 - 1.3887943997473953E-11 = -1.3250993165605518E-19
2.3195228302435696E-16 - 0.0012040908282411062 = -0.0012040908282408742
5.242885663363464E-22 - 3.6698962251221756E10 = -3.6698962251221756E10
```

I would say that Math.exp loses precision but I'm not really sure ;)